# Volley query MySQL database SQL injection

Tags: android, android-volley, sql-injection

I am running a volley (GET) request to a mysql server (from android studio) where I am trying to query the mysql database using the query in the first line of the code below. The code passes a query to an API which then applies the query to the mysql database. However, it is not working (and actually ends up causing server to be inaccessible for a few hours). I believe this is due to the fact that my query is written in such a way that it could look like sql injection. Is there a better way to (1) write the query in android studio so that it wont be perceived as sql injection? Or (2) do I have to create an API on my server and then pass the strCountry as a parameter to the API? If there is a way to do it using (1) I'd like to explore that.

Thank you.

```
        String strUrlReg = getUrl("selectjson", "Select country_region from lookup_country_regions where country_name = '" + strCountry + "'" );



        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, strUrlReg, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp2: " + "in");

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp: " + error);
                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        ClsMySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayReq);
```

Comment: Use a query parameter instead of string concatenation to put a variable into an SQL query. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html for a tutorial.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much, I've had a look at the tutorial. I get stuck on the following line: ```updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);```
I don't have an active connection set up in my code so I'm unable to run that line. Do you have any further advice on how to accomplish this? Apologies if this is a stupid question. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: It's not a stupid question - everyone has to start somewhere! :-) Yes, you need to make a connection to the database server before you can prepare or execute any query. The site I linked you to has a number of other JDBC tutorials. I recommend you start at the beginning and read as many as you find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to read through asap